# How to speed up point in polygon operations using Fiona? I have ~13 million records and a shapefile with 640 polygons

Tags: python, geospatial, fiona

with fiona.open("../data/shapefiles/Census_2011/2011_Dist.shx") as fiona_collection:

```
dict_censuscodes = {}
fiona_collections_list = list(fiona_collection)

for i in range(0,len(df_pop)):
    x = df_pop.x.iloc[i]
    y = df_pop.y.iloc[i]
    guid = df_pop.guid.iloc[i]

    point = Point(y, x)

    for shapefile_record in fiona_collections_list:
        if point.within(shape(shapefile_record['geometry'])):
            dict_censuscodes[str(guid)]=shapefile_record['properties']['censuscode']
```

Comment: Can you maybe be a bit more specific about what you are asking for? What's wrong with the code you are posting? Do you get any errors?

Comment: The code works. It just takes an insane amount of time for a large dataset. Essentially, what I am looking for is whether I can run this in parallel?